# How to convert Enum generic to work with Realm's MutableSet?

Tags: swift, enums, realm

In a Realm object, I have a `Set` which uses an enum generic:

```swift
enum Day: CaseIterable {
    case monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday
}

final class MyModel: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var days: Set<Day> = Set<Day>(Day.allCases)
}
```

It throws an error: `Generic struct 'Persisted' requires that 'Set<Day>' conform to '_Persistable'`.

Changing the `Set` to `MutableSet` does no good. It then starts throwing a new error:
`Type 'Day' does not conform to protocol 'RealmCollectionValue'`

How to solve this issue? Basically, I want `MyModel.days` property to hold distinct values from `Day` enum.

Comment: A few things: You should be using a [RealmEnum](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/swift/latest/Protocols.html#/s:10RealmSwift0A4EnumP) for your Day Enum as it's a persistable Realm Object. Then the [MutableSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/swift/data-types/mutablesets/) will be an option. A Swift `Set` is not a Realm object and will not work in that context; see [Property Types](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/swift/data-types/supported-property-types/)

Comment: Another workaround would be to save/persist your set as an array, and when you restore it you can convert it to a set once again as needed.

Comment: @Mozahler Realm does not support Arrays at all. While you could cast it to a Data type, the info would not be usable in that form (queryable). A List data type is a possibility but it does not guarantee unique values so that would have to be done in code (which is pretty simple to do)

Comment: @Jay of course you're right. I just don't remember arrays giving me a hard time, though - which is why I automatically recommended them as a substitute for a set. I'll have to take a look at how I do it myself. I do remember using List objects for a while but settled on avoiding them (generally, but not absolutely)